# Is char in unicode class?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, unicode

In .Net, given a char, is there a way to tell if that character is part of a specific Unicode category?  The categories I'm interested are defined here http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm

For example, is there a function that does anything like this?:

```
bool isCharInClass(Char c, String class)
```

that could be called like:

```
SomeClass.isCharInClass("a", "Lo");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Char.GetUnicodeCategory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.getunicodecategory.aspx) or [`CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6sx68ke.aspx) to get the unicode category (as a [`UnicodeCategory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory.aspx)).

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure how I missed that. Is it possible for a character to be in more than one category?

Comment: @BradleyUffner No - each char is in one category.

Answer (score 2):

using System.Globalization namespace

```
    Console.WriteLine("{0} , {1}", 'a', CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory('a'));
    Console.WriteLine("{0} , {1}", 'A', CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory('A'));
    Console.WriteLine("{0} , {1}", '1', CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory('1'));
    Console.WriteLine("{0} , {1}", '$', CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory('$'));
```

more documentation you could get from

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6sx68ke.aspx